# jQuery DataTables fnFilter: find the exact match of a string within a concatenated string

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables

I am using datatables and am trying to filter my table based on the presence of an ID in a hidden column.  The hidden column contains multiple IDs and they are delimited by "@" signs, e.g. @2311@11@3546@ (Note: the delimiter could be anything; we simply chose "@").

When I pass in the categoryId as a var (filterValue) to the DataTables fnFilter, I get partial matches.  For example if my categoryId=1 it will match against "1", "11" and "2311".

I want the categoryId to exactly match any of the numbers within the column, between (delimited by) the "@".  I'm pretty unfamiliar with RegEx which the fnFilter API supports and that I assume would be the best approach. I don't really have much productive code to share, unfortunately.

Here's the function I have so far:

```
var oTable = $('#fundTable').dataTable(); //the dataTable object
var filterCol = $("#table th.colCats").index(); //the index of the column to search in
$('.product-filter').click(function() { //click a link to filter the data table
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('href').match(/categoryId=([0-9]+)/)[1]; //grab the cat ID from the link
    oTable.fnFilter(filterValue, filterCol, true, false); //use fnFilter API to pass in the value, the col index, regex true/false, smart filtering true/false 
    oTable.fnDraw(); //redraw the table using filter result
    return false; //don't activate anchor link
});
```

And here's an edited version of the table I am using:

```
<table id="fundTable">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th>
                Fund
            </th>
            <th>
                Categories
            </th class="colCats">
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Fund 1
            </td>
            <td>
                @23@2311@
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Fund 2
            </td>
            <td>
                @123@4567@1234@
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I believe the DataTables API says you can use a regex expression in place of the value (filterValue).  I'm just not sure how to write it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? As it is it's impossible to figure out what you're asking without an example of your code too.

Comment: Sure.  I have updated question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple - I do something very similar in some of my code (though I used '=' to either side of my IDs - adjust accordingly):

```
    oTable.fnFilter('=' + filterValue + '=', filterCol);
    oTable.fnDraw();
```

Since the default filtering looks for the string anywhere within the column, no further regex wizardry is needed.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It seems to work for a single value, e.g. "@123@" but the filter retrieves no records when pattern matching within a column with multiple values, e.g. "@123@345@678@"

Comment: I spoke too soon.  It does work for two or more integers, just not for single integers.  Not sure why but it's likely something on my end.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you still using 'true, false' for the third and fourth arguments in the fnFilter call? If so, try removing or reversing them - those are flipped from the default values which I use.

Comment: As I suspected, user error.  I had assumed that the single digit categories were in the JSON object I was using to search against.  Well they weren't - but are now.  And it now works like a charm.  Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, however I only needed to match input sequentially.  For me this worked, adding `^` before the value and adding the 3rd param (regex) to `true`.

> Note: this was used in conjunction with a input that had a jQuery
>   keyup function attached, hence the complex second parameter.

```
 oTable.fnFilter("^" + this.value,
 oTable.oApi._fnVisibleToColumnIndex(binding.gridId.fnSettings(),  
 $("thead input").index(this)), true );
```

Comment: thanks William, this idea of adding `^` worked for me